# Why does the inner rectangle overflow the outer rectangle in Vega spec

Tags: border, vega

This is the Vega spec, it is intended to contain two equally-sized groups in one row:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "autosize": "none",
  "config": {"group": {"stroke": "black"}},
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "target_height",
      "value": 200},
    {
      "name": "target_width",
      "update": "5/4 * target_height"},
    {
      "name": "level_0_padding",
      "update": "1/16 * target_height"},
    {
      "name": "level_1_padding",
      "update": "1/2 * level_0_padding"},
    {
      "name": "level_0_height",
      "update": "target_height - 2*level_0_padding"},
    {
      "name": "level_0_width",
      "update": "target_width - 2*level_0_padding"},
    {
      "name": "level_1_width",
      "update": "1/2 * (level_0_width - level_0_padding)"},
    {
      "name": "level_1_height",
      "update": "level_0_height"}],
  "width": {"signal": "level_0_width"},
  "height": {"signal": "level_0_height"},
  "padding": {"signal": "level_0_padding"},
  "layout": {
    "padding": {"signal": "level_0_padding"},
    "align": "all",
    "center": true},
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "encode": {"update": {
        "width": {"signal": "level_1_width"},
        "height": {"signal": "level_1_height"},
        "padding": {"value": 0},
        "stroke": {"value": "red"},
        "strokeOpacity": {"value": 0.5}}}},
    {
      "type": "group",
      "encode": {"update": {
        "width": {"signal": "level_1_width"},
        "height": {"signal": "level_1_height"},
        "padding": {"value": 0},
        "stroke": {"value": "red"},
        "strokeOpacity": {"value": 0.5}}}}]}
```

For some reason, however, the second group seems to overflow the global plot space:
[image: overflowing bounding boxes]

It seems that the overflow is always about a few pixels wide, independently of the values of `target_width`, `target_height` or `level_0_padding`.

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhBIGmNhBoAvOGhDiJamVAkAzGmTSgyAJzYMcxkBEzmA1mvRMANkij2QAXy8ylZcSQXCDQAbVBAhCcQTCRTMjhMAH14QyxpEGIghicAJgAGfN8IpCj1WPjEpIB3GgATegzLOqRMaIECABYAAgAqboqE5NSydOKNUuiXOFIXJPyknCQ6uppxIxlm1uiARgIdgDY+gbihlLg0zG8pErL0admkncXl1fWmnBa29T3c44e4HMFksVmsjONIlMZoD5udLh8vtFBlURlhugBabq5XoAoEvUHvCGTdS42G1BowBHbcqnKrk+gYrE46F4kFvcE3CZ3ECk570ymbT7U9C-Y4AClJC35jMl+PZAEprrcoY9nqiroLESSWbD1d4ALoyfnWfyBFzax5S+qNXwYC6jK6oUCmoIWmELPW2tlgk2GM1u1mvH22twATwsjtA3veTpsftd9x1wKDhJkQT96iC5p0cHEbVMaDsOVtyFM9hCqHCMVDOGiZgsVhkud0dScoC231jxtjLvNidVNWtlNtep78b7PJ1avtYxk0aMsayLhyaCKfjsbEc1iXK-QpjgdWuNg3jgA8ksoHRQ9vsk58pQBD4fJzMDW6+ZLBlm2xW9YO22QG7Z1xwDJ5BwpI9R2AgIE0nAdPTnFMF1AHc71tWwHAA1D1H3Q90JPOBz3cK8b2XO8HyfLx9S8IA)

Note that the issue remains if the signal update expressions are rewritten like in the following example, to exclude user floating-point error as the cause of the issue:

```
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "target_height",
      "value": 200},
    {
      "name": "target_width",
      "update": "5/4 * target_height"},
    {
      "name": "level_0_padding",
      "update": "1/16 * target_height"},
    {
      "name": "level_1_padding",
      "update": "1/32 * target_height"},
    {
      "name": "level_0_height",
      "update": "7/8 * target_height"},
    {
      "name": "level_0_width",
      "update": "9/8 * target_height"},
    {
      "name": "level_1_width",
      "update": "17/32 * target_height"},
    {
      "name": "level_1_height",
      "update": "level_0_height"}],
```

In fact, the overflow happens even if all of the signals have integer values.

#### The same issue, but with a column instead of a row

[image: overflow on bottom]

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhBIGmNhBoAvOGhDiJamVAkAzGmTSgyAJzYMcxkBEzmA1mvRMANkij2QAXy8ylZcSQXCDQAbVBAhCcQTCRTMjhMAH14QyxpEGIghicAJgAGfN8IpCj1WPjEpIB3GgATegyslxy0AqKpErL0FzhSFyT8pJwkOrqacSMZZtbUAA5ijVLo3v6kgEZh0fHJjMs6pExo9YJcgAIAKjPVuAGhkbGJo0XIlb7bwZS4NMw9nAOjuU4glkqkyFgzgBaM65C43O5bR67F7LdTwz61BowP4A6IVEE1er0KEwuHvBEPHbPTpLbogdGbMHpGT7Q7HU6XM4ACnRQyZmBJvMRVIAlN4aa80eSNoSsTi2VK1kNMY0vABdGQq7GoUD+QIuRUfZVE7G+DDfcG-HU2Qz6w0I-nikCUp7WPVBe2fF3ImRuACeFitoF0LQQ4hCqHWMm9Rmt7oNPWl922rrNQVt6iCBp0cHER1MaDsOTNyFM9gj4Rifpw0TMFisMlzujqTlArMB1q1bttHsTa02XbNjrjPYT9OljIt6TNMesMycHRsdjYjjn2WipjgdSdtgccAA8iMoHQ-WuWgvKAIfD4aZhq7XzJYMk22C3rO3WyAuyOAr3x-3ZVVGRh11UdPUnH4nVna15zQRddxXT9YPQTdtzNBDHEPdwTzPWZ8kva91S8IA)

#### With a more complex layout

Trying to do the same thing, but with a slightly more complicated layout results in accumulated overflows and, even worse, the two red boxes/groups are misaligned:

[image: horrible]

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhBIGmNhBoAvOGhDiJamVAkAzGmTSgyAJzYMcxkBEzmA1mvRMANkij2QAXy8ylZcSQXCDQAbVBAhCcQTCRTMjhMAH14QyxpEGIghicAJgAGfN8IpCj1WPjEpIB3GgATegyslxy0AGZC4o1S6Jc4Uhck-KScJDq6mnEjGWbW1ABGADYuyN7+uEH5kbGJqYzLOqRMaPmCXIACACpzvoGh7fHJoxWe9VuNpNyH3emQA6OTgQACxXG7rQbDUaPPYvMrod4QlJwNKYfY4Q7HcpxBLJVJkLDnAC051ylwR9yhP28UhKcJA5OGtQaMDRGOiFRxNXq9CJJLJ4IpOye1NpazuWyZjRk-0x6FOF2uAAoGVzmbyVZSngBKEXdOnkrZ49LS9EAt4C4ZG1FeAC6MklLNQoH8gRc5rujO5LN8GGR+NRTpshld7o+lr96R9mr2gZdQVDiOjzxkbgAnhYA6Ak9Y4274RbvsKfUFg+ogm6dHBxMdTGg7DkfchTPYQqhwjFUzhomYLFY-MGgq326sE59VVK-qbZfSBRKvbqR-m7l8rayzXKzqDlbOkSj1TukzrbTIq7o6k5QDKLyAHTmB3mZ+Lx96ZKvY-fR4aI9aZNnA7MnCKPw7DYRxrAA9RTDgOpqRsEDHAAeVGKA6FTcDskAygBB8H00wzaw-2dD8lw+LZsx9XQWgQcRW3mGQSwCMsXArEAoCrGs61MBsZCbFswlATBO27cxLAyU82HPawr2sW93wCeMSMGL5bx9N8iPkh9yRXb9YMIzIMLQIC4Ica8IOcFo1B9WwTKQ9xUPQizDMoXJsJwmkOy7dQe1Ek9xDPa9pMDWT1JDRSkjnZlYLUoMNNHbSUV0oUY1AMyjOs0DTIM8zWis+C4FslDBIcuZ8mc1yfBtLpBM89BvL7GLXSHUU4ufNdpwNVrYTFD54v9NrATaLcOqtXlSQ6w9vDtEBxMkwNAtAYKGoUx9SM618dLk0KVs2Xc+qjJKjH-LK0ry4roigmDcps5D7KOxzUFK8qUyQdN5AIg671isKyI+ii2Comi0Do2QXFLdBywyNjqzgWtUHrOBGziPi2wEoSvJE+qZoCqdr0W3MWpU9aEs25atN2yNfw+u6SqujKzvUVwcuA667KK6nMJcnCqrR2qMbEvyJOxtkZPnEnNIFZT51UjaQtJiXyZ-EA9NS2mwPZhnHNV-KbrZlLjrKrn3Oq4Te35-ypJxkXIrFgmpaJvqbbC3qKaVqm9fuk6TPp7LLOZjKCtu92SoNnDKsqoA)

After playing around with this example, I conclude that the misalignment is actually a separate issue, as it can be fixed by specifying `"align": "none"` instead of `"align": "each"` or `"align": "all"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need "bounds": "flush".

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "autosize": "none",
  "config": {"group": {"stroke": "black"}},
  "signals": [
    
    {"name": "level_0_padding", "value": 16},
    {"name": "level_1_padding", "update": "1/2 * level_0_padding"},
    {"name": "level_0_height", "update": "168"},
    {"name": "level_0_width", "update": "168"},
    {
      "name": "level_1_width",
      "update": "1/2 * (level_0_width - level_0_padding)"
    },
    {"name": "level_1_height", "update": "level_0_height"}
  ],
  "width": {"signal": "168"},
  "height": {"signal": "168"},
  "padding": {"signal": "30"},
  "layout": {"padding": {"signal": "level_0_padding"}, "bounds": "flush"},
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "width": {"signal": "level_1_width"},
          "height": {"signal": "level_1_height"},
          "padding": {"value": 0},
          "stroke": {"value": "red"},
          "strokeOpacity": {"value": 0.5}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "group",
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "width": {"signal": "level_1_width"},
          "height": {"signal": "level_1_height"},
          "padding": {"value": 0},
          "stroke": {"value": "red"},
          "strokeOpacity": {"value": 0.5}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```